# 4-20mA current loop - transmit sensor reading

Tags: transistors, heat, thermocouple, 4-20ma, compensation

I am working on design loop current transmitter- to transmit reading value from thermocouple sensor using below design. I measured co-junction temperature using NTC instead of RTD.

During applying supply and connect load resister 500 ohms at Vloop-, the current flow 4-20mA when input is 0-100 degree. My co-junction reading start to increase from 25 degree to 27 degree.

My problem was when applying supply, BJT bc548 heats up when sensing current. It makes Co-junction temperature increases then my input temperature reading is not accurated.

I try to place NTC near input terminals and all the circuit is inside the small closed case. wherever I tried to place NTC, my co-junction reading still drifting from the heat of BC548.

I wonder Is there a away to reduce BJT heat during sensing the current?

[image: current loop design]

Comment: Do you have any control over the voltage supplied to the loop (indicated as "4V to 28V" on the schematic)?

Comment: @ThePhoton When I test, I apply only 24V. I didn't tested other level voltage yet. I have TVS SMAJ30CA only

Comment: The lower you can make this, the less power your BJT will consume, and the less it will heat up.

Comment: Note however, 4 V might not actually work. I'd stick with 5 V or so as a minimum if you want to actually be able to get 20 mA output while keeping the ADP1720 in regulation.

Comment: @ThePhoton sorry for lack of information, my design need to work at 10-24V supply.

Comment: Not much you can do then. Whatever transistor you use there will be producing ~400 mW heat at 20 mA output. Only thing you can do is mechanically find a way to keep that heat away from the thermocouple. But without any idea about your physical/mechanical setup there's no way we can advise on that.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you so much then. At least it makes me know that there is no way to make the heat goes away. I will keep find the way to block or keep out the heat.