# install heatsink on BJT

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, heat, thermal, heatsink

I am facing the problem with the heat of transistor disturb sensor reading. Here the link [refer problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/417402/4-20ma-current-loop-transmit-sensor-reading?noredirect=1#comment1033443_417402)
I am using BC548 transistor. It is a bit hot when operating because it disipates power around 400mW. Its temparature is around 50 degree celcius. It is inside a case with the rest of my circuit. So I want to reduce the heat of transistor.

My question is...

1. Is it going to help to reduce transistor heat if I install transistor with a heatsink? I am not sure because BC847 seems not to have thermal pad.
2. If install a heatsink helps, Is it still reduce the heat if I place the heatsink inside my case and near a tiny hole there.

[image: My case]

Comment: A heatsink helps the heat to leave the transistor. You need the heat to leave the enclosure. So heatsinking your transistor won't help you.

Comment: Small transistors like the BC548 aren't a good choice to dissipate 400mW continuously. As part of the heat can leave via the electrical leads, it might help to increase the size of the copper area on the PCB where the transistor is connected. But as brhans says, heat needs to get out and the plastic housing you show does not help, plastic does not conduct heat very well. And no, that small hole doesn't help. **If** you can guarantee that the transistor never gets warmer than 50C that could be OK. But it can be that problems only occur after weeks, months or years of operation.

Comment: Is that case an off the shelf thing or something you had custom made?

Comment: @MichaelKaras It is off the shelf thing. But I can make any slightly modification with it, depends on how complicate that is.

Comment: Did you guess or measure case temp ? One r more of the leads should have been Much hotter than the case maybe 80'C . If you cannot lower the voltage ratings, then a wide length of metal between the plastic and a TO-220 would be cooler.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I measured temparature on BC548 package using thermistor.

Answer (score 3):

If I was faced with the problem that you have I would made modifications to the case design. The worst case 400mW is hard to get out of the fully plastic case. On the other hand that power level is not too bad if you could get the heat flow to the outside.

I would made the case in such a way that it has one of:

1. A metal cup base
2. A side metal band all the way around
3. A metal disk bottom

One of these approaches can be leveraged to act as a heatsink for the heat generating transistor. Of course you will want to do this in a way that the metal heatsink piece is full isolated electrically from the rest of the circuit.

Comment: This would be my approach as well. Another option might be to cut slots in the case for forced airflow, too.

Comment: @Hearth air flow does not really help until you have a relatively large temperature differential or some sort of chimney effect to multiply the flow due to a small differential.

Comment: @EdgarBrown is "around 50°C" not large enough? That's about 30° above ambient or more unless it's a really hot day outside.

Comment: @@MichaelKaras Thank you for your answering. If one of the terminal is not used. Can I use it as a heatsink?

Comment: @BEWTYRodbanyang - Not nearly enough surface area.

Comment: @EdgarBrown air flow does not help????  Why do enclosures have vents?  Air flow increases convection big time.  Every little bit helps.  Little things add up to big stuff.  Vents should be at top and bottom.   This adds another thermal path for the heat to move from the case to ambient.  Without vents the temperature in the enclosure will increase.  Not a lot of options here.

Comment: @Misunderstood no, it does not unless (1) the temperature is high enough and (2) the flow is significant enough. Air is a very poor thermal conductor and has a very low thermal capacity, unless you have a large enough temperature differential even a fan could add more power than the power that is removed by the air flow (I have dealt with such designs). Granted, some airflow is better than none but to drive that airflow you need a considerable temperature differential, as I very clearly stated.

Comment: If you keep pumping heat into the enclosure, without venting, the air inside the enclosure will, over time, approach the temperature of the case.   50° C case and 30° differential is not insignificant.   Bottom line, vents WILL help and take little effort to implement.   No need to debate further.  I agree to disagree.  And the liquor is kicking in.

Answer (score 1):

> If one of the terminal is not used. Can I use it as a heatsink?

If you use a heavy gauge solid copper wire from the case to the terminal and also attach a heatsink to the terminal, that will at least help.

You could use both a ground thermal (any terminal if case is electrically isolated) and the free terminal then mount a heating between the two terminals.  I would pick a terminal directly across from the free terminal if possible.  The thicker the wire and the more wires the better.

It would help if the wire were in direct contact with the heatsink.

The thermal resistance of a copper wire is small enough to conduct a fair amount of heat. More than a PCB copper layer.  But you need more surface area than just the wire and terminal.

I would use a heatsink like this (1" x 0.6" x 0.3" costs 19¢):
[image]
Source: [0.601" Wide Extruded Aluminum Heatsink](https://www.heatsinkusa.com/0-601-wide-extruded-aluminum-heatsink/)

If 0.3 inch is too high then use a copper plate cut to expose as much surface as possible. Thicker is better for lateral heat conduction.

If height is not an issue use a heatsink with higher fins.

[Heatsink USA](https://www.heatsinkusa.com/home/) has good prices and good variety of extruded aluminum heatsinks.

---

**Theory**

Look at the bar between T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub> as the wire from the case to the terminal.

The length reduces heat conductivity.
Increasing cross sectional area (more and thicker wire) increases thermal conductivity.
You want high thermal conductivity so the heat will move quickly.

[image]

[image]

Where:

k=material conductivity (e.g. copper is better than aluminum)
A=cross sectional area (higher is better, thicker and more wires)
T<sub>1</sub> **-** T<sub>2</sub> = temperature differential
d=distance (length of wire, lower is better)

Q=heat flux
t=time (higher k & A, lower ambient temp, and shorter wire moves heat faster)

A greater temperature differential will move heat faster. Cooler ambient is better.